# Can you have a closure that has both capture list and parameter list?

Tags: swift, parameters, closures, swift2

In Swift, how you create a closure that has both capture list and parameters?

I have used code presented in either form, but do not know how to create a closure that has both parameters and capture list.

e.g.

Closure with parameter list:

```
myFunction {
    (x: Int, y: Int) -> Int in
    return x + y
}
```

Closure with capture list:

```
myFunction { [weak parent = self.parent] in print(parent!.title) }
```

Example attempt with capture list:

```
class MyTest {
    var value:Int = 3

    func myFunction(f: (x:Int, y:Int) -> Int) {
        print(f(x: self.value, y: 5))
    }

    func testFunction() {
        myFunction {
            [weak self] (x, y) in   //<--- This won't work, how to specify weak self here?
            print(self.value)
            return self.value + y
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here. Did you try making a closure that has both?

Comment: Yes, would like to know if that's possible.  I tried a few different ways and couldn't nail the syntax.

Comment: @0x7fffffff It would be great if you can take a look into how to solve the abuse of downvotes.  I am asking a proper question and two downvotes hit already.

Comment: I don't see anything indicating that votes are being abused here. Although I didn't personally down vote this question, I can only assume that those who have did so because you've posed an "is it possible" kind of problem without showing the attempts that you're already made to solve it. Moving forward, I think you'll get better responses if you include information like this in your questions.

Comment: All the attempts are rubbish because they don't work. Why would someone who knows the answer care to look at such thing? If I had included the things I have tried, would you say there is no more ground for downvoting? Asking this so I can make questions as solid as possible.

Comment: showing incorrect attempts at solving a problem helps us see your thought process, which may (in general) help with the writing of answers that are specifically geared towards clearing up the misunderstanding. More importantly though, including this kind of information in a question helps show potential answerers that you put thought and effort into solving a problem before posting here. I can't tell you that including this information will prevent down votes altogether (people will vote as they please), but had this question contained this information, I think it would be a decent one.

Comment: Added incorrect attempt per your suggestion.

Comment: @Boon Thanks for asking this, I was having a hard time finding the correct syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example you've given *does* work. To specify both a parameter list and a capture list you just do:

```
exampleFunctionThatTakesClosure() { [weak self] thing1, thing2 in
}
```

However, creating a weak reference via a parameter list means that `self` within your closure becomes an optional - as such, you have to unwrap (or force unwrap) it before you can use its value.

For example, force unwrapping:

```
func testFunction() {
    myFunction {
        [weak self] (x, y) in

        print(self!.value)
        return self!.value + y
    }
}
```

Or:

```
func testFunction() {
    myFunction {
        [weak self] (x, y) in

        if let weakSelf = self {
            print(weakSelf.value)
            return weakSelf.value + y
        } else {
            return y
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the weak ref part.